# TFS update workspace to specific version c#

Tags: c#, tfs, changeset

I have a mounted TFS workspace and I'm trying to iterate a list of change sets, and update my mounted workspace to each version.

Here is my code:

```
// Update the local workspace (repositoryDir) to a specific 
// changeset number (newChangeSetNumber)
public static void UpdateToChangeSet(string repositoryDir, int newChangeSetNumber)
{
     var currentWorkspace = VcServer.GetWorkspace(repositoryDir);

     currentWorkspace.Get(VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec(
                          String.Format("C{0}", newChangeSetNumber), null), 
                          GetOptions.GetAll);
}
```

This operation takes too long (I suspect it downloads the entire workspace instead of just downloading the changed files).

How can I get only the changed files?

Comment: GetAll will get all files AFAIU (like /force in tf.exe command line). Try to specify GetOptions.None - seems that you don't need any additional options to get specific version

Comment: Ok, and what will overwrite do then?

Comment: Use `GetOptions.Overwrite` to overwrite changed/checked out files.